# I can't find my CLASSPATH and I'm sure how to set it?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I install JDK in apt-get way, and now I can't find CLASSPATH in my Ubuntu.
so I want to set by myself.I add such line in to ~/.bashrc

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_73/lib/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14/*
```

and then run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

but when I try

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

I get nothing. what should I add into .bashrc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange. But to isolate other systemic issues, why don't you `export` from your shell and try:

```
$ export CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jdk1.8.0_73/lib/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14.jar
$ echo ${CLASSPATH}
```

Assuming this works, see if you are actually `sourcing` other file in `~/.bashrc`. Add `set -x` at the top of `~/.bashrc` to debug it.

Comment: I find there are two different versions of my computer. openjdk and oracle jdk. and I uninstall openjdk. and then every is fine. I'm not sure what happen, but I need go on. Thank you any way.